# Found a bad link on one of your pages

Tags: support, stack-overflow

This page has a bad scam on it. Clicking Answer One "this page" will lock your computer:

[How to customize bootstrap switch color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575437/how-to-customize-bootstrap-switch-color)

Comment: Please ask at the site specific meta first, before it's not confirmed to be a network wide big.

Comment: I've edited the link to point to an archived version of the page. As explained in the answer below, if you find another broken link in the future you have the ability to fix it yourself.

Comment: As this question is about a situation on *one specific site* in the Stack Exchange network, unfortunately, we have to mark this question as "off-topic" for this site. Each site has a *per-site meta* where you can ask questions about that site, which can be accessed through the site switcher on the top right corner. Questions on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, are expected to relate to the entire SE network as a whole, not just one specific site.

Comment: All of this is great guys. I looked on SO and could not find where to post my discovery. I'm just doing a service.

Answer (score 6):

You've already joined Stack Overflow. You should be able to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575437/how-to-customize-bootstrap-switch-color/edit#) that answer and remove the offending link. If you don't have enough reputation to edit it outright, your changes will be put in a review queue for people with enough reputation to review them, but "removing malicious link" should be a good enough reason for any reasonable reviewer to approve the edit.